# Time formatting, strtotime, php Date ()

Tags: php, time, scripting

> Time formatting, strtotime, php Date ()

I am trying to insert "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm", into the database using strtotime from an input value.

When I retrieved the value using php date(d-m-Y H:i), i am about 7-9 hrs behind....I am guess it s a timezone thing, but the server and me are in the same zone (i think).

How can I make the value stored the same as the value coming out? this is for a date display format.

EDIT: removing strtotime now gives me 01-01-1970 00:00....so whats the problem? isnt the "-" supposed to be euro format?

Comment: Why use strings, that you're converting back and forth? Why not use `DateTime` all the way through, which you can turn into a string at any given time (`$dateTimeInst->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`), and you can add/remove intervals to it... check the `DateTime` documentation apges

Comment: If you think it might be a time-zone issue, just explicitly set the timezone to what you want it to be with `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');`,

Comment: that makes sense, i guess, LOL Thought i might skip a step later if the date is in unix timestamp in the database

Comment: this is for a forum package so anyone can be anywhere, BUT i assume the timezone is from the server timezone anways?

Comment: I just want to know why this occurs thats all

Comment: EDIT: removing strtotime now gives me 01-01-1970 00:00....so whats the problem? isnt the "-" supposed to be euro format?